# Asp.Net Core 2 Validating bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, authorization, bearer-token

I am struggling to find an exact way of validating my `OAuth` `bearer` token which is passed when a request is sent to the API am working on which is a `Asp.Net core` project.

The purpose here is to extract the bearer token and `Validate` it and if all is fine then continue with the request.

So far my findings have come across the following

- JWT bear token authorization which mostly talks about `access_token`
- Asp.Net core security middleware
- Custom Authorize attribute which handle this.

I am not really sure how I can achieve my validation? Should I extract the bearer token and then create a custom validating method?

Ideally would like the `[Authorize]` attribute to handle this.

Suggestions please?

Comment: Have you identified which flow you want to use?

Comment: @AustinTFrench as mentioned would ideally like to go the attribute way. However, even creating custom auth attribute in asp.net core is somewhat limited?

Comment: attribute key? So specific grants in your JWT? I'd consider the Authorization grant, and get the additional grants via the API. And .NET core isn't limited, as much as it has changed a lot. Core 2 uses different libraries and methods (even in start up configuration) than 1.0, and 2.3 changed it again. Who knows what Core 3 will do...

Comment: @AustinTFrench can you explain more about the Authorization grant?

Comment: There's a ton out there (check the spec or start at https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/ ), and we would go way into the weeds in comments

Comment: @AustinTFrench checked out the link for Authorization grant. If I am not wrong, but it redirects to the OAuth server where user accepts the request and accordingly authorization is granted. However in my case I have a access token which requires validation.

Comment: Am now looking into https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide which uses JWT

Comment: Given the changing scenarios of jwt and oauth in asp.net core, a safe bet would be to go with openIdConnect. It makes your life easier, and at this moment is future proof!

Comment: @HimanshuPant I don't have a option. I have to use OAuth Bearer tokens as suppose to JWT or OpenIdConnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well finally after more research I finally found that custom `AuthorizationHandler` is a more suitable solution as suppose to using custom `Authorize` attributes which is not suggested in Asp.Net Core.

It was simple to setup and I am able to extract my `Bearer` token from the header for further authorization with `OAuth`.

Here is a my approach:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHandler: IAuthorizationHandler
{
   public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
   {
       var authFilterCtx = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext)context.Resource;
       string authHeader = authFilterCtx.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
       if (authHeader != null && authHeader.Contains("Bearer"))
       {
          var token = authHeader.Replace("Bearer", "");
          // Now token can be used for further authorization
       }

       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Lastly registering the handler in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomAuthorizationHandler>();
}
```

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#what-should-a-handler-return instead of throwing exception it is better “ To guarantee failure, even if other requirement handlers succeed, call context.Fail.”

Answer (score 1):

I think to put the following code snippet inside **ConfigureServices()** should be able to validate your access_token after installing *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer* NuGet package:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                //options.SaveToken = true;
                options.MetadataAddress = ValidationEndPoint;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,

                    ValidIssuer = tokenIssuer,
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { clientId },
                    ValidAudience = null
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            });
        });
```

remember to put **app.UseAuthentication()** and **app.UseAuthorization()** in the Configure() method. And add **[authorize]** to your controller API.